# Getting error str variable cannot be passed

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String st = "10+300";
    int result;
    for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++)
    {

        if(st.charAt(i)=='+')
        {
            result=Integer.parseInt(st);//getting error in this line
            System.out.print(result);
        }         
    }

}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` doesn't do you think it does.

Comment: The input to `Integer.parseInt` must be the string form of one integer; it will not perform arithmetic for you.

Comment: Integer.parseInt is not an `eval`...

Comment: "Getting error" is *never* enough information. A compile-time error? An exception? What are the details? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: '+' is not an int ...

Comment: The [documentation for parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) is very clear that this is not allowed. Only decimal digits (and a leading minus sign) are valid input.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific string that you have in your code, you can do:

```
result0 = Integer.parseInt(st.split("+")[0]);
result1 = Integer.parseInt(st.split("+")[1]);
```

But you cannot do:

```
result = Integer.parseInt(st);
```

Comment: You may want to explain *why* he cannot do the second, as well as why the first works for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to parse a string which doesn't represent a number. `10+300` is not a number, but `+10300` would be